# Sentry create-react-app source maps configuration "could not determine a source map reference"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vercel, sentry, source-maps

I have a create-react-app-based React application that is currently deployed on **Vercel**. I have tried multiple ways (Craco.js, react-app-rewired, etc.) to avoid using `npm run eject` and modifying the Webpack configuration to use Sentry Webpack plugin as mentioned in the official documentation [Webpack for React | Sentry Documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/sourcemaps/uploading/webpack).

Every time the source maps are properly getting generated and configured on the dev environment but on production the logs of Vercel look like this:

[Vercel Logs Production](https://pastebin.com/4eUwvfj4)

[Vercel Logs Staging](https://pastebin.com/YhxvSUd6)

I need to get source maps up and running on production as soon as possible but nothing seems to work. Please let me know how should I proceed with this.

I have rechecked my confir-overrides.js file in the case of react-app-rewired and craco.config.js file when I was using craco.js multiple times but everything seems to be a file. The issue isn't with sentry configuration because sources are being generated and uploaded to the sentry on the staging environment but when deploying on production there seem to be some issues because the source map files are not being referenced by the js chunks. It seems that the chunks are missing the referencing comment at the end of the file.

I have also tried experimenting with `sourceMapFilename` property under `output` property of webpack config but that also doesn't seem to work.